# PHP - how to terminate python script from php page?

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi

I am currently working on my final year project which is IoT based. I have a website written in php and I have sensors which are controlled by the raspberry pi board using python script. One of the functions I want to develop is that the user can control the sensors by turn them on/off via the web page. what I mean by turning on/off is to run or terminate python script from running.

I could execute the python file from the web page and it works fine using shell_execute(python fileName.py). however for the termination, I could not, even I tried different ways to do so. The problem I have faced is the script keeps running in the background.

Please help if anyone has an idea of how to stop python script from web page(php page - pressing a button for example).

Thank you

Comment: You would want to find the PID of the process then kill it, though i think a better way would be to have an sqlite database which holds the states and values of your sensors and the python process works from/on that. This way your simply setting a flag in a db not fiddling with pids/permissions/systemd etc.

Comment: I believe this may answer your question [How do I stop a python script from running via a webpage?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23615/how-do-i-stop-a-python-script-from-running-via-a-webpage)

Answer (score 0):

From terminal

```
sudo visudo
```

Add

```
www-data  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/kill
```

Create a PHP file and add

```
<?php
shell_exec ('sudo kill -9 $(pgrep -f python)');
?>
```

You can make a button to call the PHP file to kill all running Python processes.